# Defining facets on a date range

Tags: thinking-sphinx

I want to define a facet on a date range.Is this possible?

For example I have many requests and I want to have a facet displaying
something like this:

Requests today(2)
Requests this week(10)
Requests this month(245)

where 2,10 and 245 are the number of requests raised on this day,this
week and this month respectively.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to:
http://groups.google.com/group/thinking-sphinx/browse_thread/thread/e7a8f18f8e064d5c

Comment: ...and more recently: http://groups.google.com/group/thinking-sphinx/browse_thread/thread/cb2814555ee77e9f/e607ed86d86147e8